# Temporary table information left over on InnoDB data dictionary after a db crash while a alter table was runnig

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6, data-dictionary

After a database crash while the system was running an alter table command I'm getting the following message during mysqld initialization:

```
2024-02-25 19:58:48 7fa2f9e84880  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2024-02-25 19:58:48 12426 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'dshopd6_virtual/#sql-63ef_11ac1'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2024-02-25 19:58:48 12426 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"dshopd6_virtual"."#sql-63ef_11ac1"', ignored.
```

The database starts with no other issues and operates normally.

The .frm/.ibd files no longer exists but the references to those files and table objects are still on the InnoDB data dictionary in the tables in information_schema.

Drop temporary table doesn't work since the datafile no longer existis.

My question is: can I manually remove the references to this object from the tables on the data dictionay?

The info is located on tables:

INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES

INNODB_SYS_TABLES

INNODB_SYS_INDEXES

INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS

INNODB_SYS_FIELDS

INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES

INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS

Or should I just let this be and don't mess with the data dictionary?

Thank you.

Comment: File a bug report ... bugs.mysql.com